# PHP for ; foreach variable scope

Tags: php, loops, variables, scope

Do variables in the for / foreach loop have a local scope? If so, how do I make it global?

page.php:

```
<?php
$title = "2";                  
$menu[0] = "1";   
$menu[1] = "2";
$menu[2] = "3";
$menu[3] = "4";
$menu[4] = "5";
$menu[5] = "6";
$menu[6] = "7";
$menu[7] = "8";


foreach ($menu as $value){ 

if ($title == $value){   
       $active = "active";
       echo "if " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
} 
else {
     $active = "";
     echo "else " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
}}

include "header.php"; 

foreach ($menu as $value) {
var_dump($active);
    echo "$value <br>";
}


include "header.php"; 
?>

<!-- begin page content -->
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
<!-- end page content -->

<?php
include "footer.php";                
?>
```

Essentially, I have this line in the header.php:

```
<li class="mainNav <?php echo $active; ?>" style="z-index:8">
<a href="http://www.com"><?php echo $menu[0]; ?></a></li>
```

I want the list to have **class="mainNav active"** if it's that page and **class="mainNav"** if not.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

So I created a function from @urfusion suggestion. Now page.php:

```
<?php
$title = "2";                  
$menu[0] = "1";   
$menu[1] = "2";
$menu[2] = "3";
$menu[3] = "4";
$menu[4] = "5";
$menu[5] = "6";
$menu[6] = "7";
$menu[7] = "8;
?>


<?php


function mainNav($menu) {


foreach ($menu as $value){ 

 if ($title == $value){   
       $active = "active";
       echo "if " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] . " <br /><br />";
   } 
   else {
     $active = " ";
     echo "else " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] . " <br /><br />";
    }  


echo "function" . $active . $value;
  return $active;

}
}


include "header.php"; 
?>


<!-- begin page content -->
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
<!-- end page content -->

<?php
include "footer.php";                
?>
```

And the header.php:

```
 <li class="mainNav <?php mainNav(); ?>" style="z-index:8">
<a href="http://www.com"><?php echo $menu[1]; ?></a></li>
```

Still nothing and now I seem to have lost the output of the echo statements ...

Comment: initialize `$active`  before `foreach` loop

Comment: "Do variables in the for / foreach loop have a local scope?" - loops, switch/cases, try-catch blocks etc do not constitute scopes in php. see https://3v4l.org/WjX5Q

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. the second foreach completely throw me off!

Comment: Are you even sure the `$title` is a global, as in, usable below in your method? To me it looks like you should be using a clause like `using (...)` in your function declaration

Answer (score 18):

> Do variables in the for / foreach loop have a local scope? If so, how do I make it global?

There are only two kinds of scopes in PHP: the global scope and local function scope.

A local function scope contains the function's parameters and the variables that are set inside the function body. The scope is created when the function is invoked and it is destroyed when the execution of the function completes.

The global scope contains all the variables that are set by the code outside any function. It is created when the main script (the one invoked by the interpreter) starts.

The [`include`d](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [`require`d](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) files do not create new scopes. The code that is outside functions in the included files runs in the scope where the `include` or `require` statement is placed. This means, global scope if the `include` statement appears outside any function of the local scope of the function that contains the `include` statement. All four include statements (`include`, `include_once`, `require`, `require_once`) work the same regarding this matter.

Any variable is available in its scope since it was set for the very first time until it is removed using [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) or until its scope is destroyed.

Read more about [`variables scope`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

---

To answer your question: if the `for` or `foreach` loop is placed in a function then the variables they define have local scope (the scope of the function); otherwise they have global scope.

---

The problem in your code (the bad indentation doesn't help you see it) is in the first `foreach`.

This is the code properly indented:

```
foreach ($menu as $value) {
    if ($title == $value) {
        $active = "active";
        echo "if " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
    } else {
        $active = "";
        echo "else " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
    }
}
```

The problem is obvious: it modifies the value of variable `$active` on each iteration. All but the last assignment of `$active` is useless. Only the last one counts. And, most probably, on the last iteration it takes the `else` branch of `if ($title == $value)` and `$active` becomes `''` (the empty string).

There are several simple solutions for the problem. For example, you can display the menu inside the aforementioned `foreach`:

```
foreach ($menu as $value) {
    if ($title == $value) {
        $active = "active";
    } else {
        $active = "";
    }
    ?>
    <li class="mainNav <?php echo $active; ?>" style="z-index:8">
    <a href="http://www.com"><?php echo $value; ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
```

In fact, all this stuff should go into `header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like

```
$active = "";
foreach ($menu as $value){ 

   if ($title == $value){   
       $active = "active";
       echo "if " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
   } 
   else {
     $active = "";
     echo "else " . $active. $title . $menu[$x] ." <br /><br />";
   }
}
```

In PHP, variables can be declared anywhere in the script.

The scope of a variable is the part of the script where the variable can be referenced/used.

PHP has three different variable scopes:

```
local
global
static
```

for more information on [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: I'm getting the correct echo statements but it's not changing the header.php. I'm wondering if that's because the foreach loop is not contained in the header.php document or if it's something else ...

Comment: you can not use a variable in other file without passing it through any `function` or `url` or `session` variable.

Comment: Only the last value that has been assigned to $active will be retained when header.php is included (_after_ the loop). In your example the last assignement is in the loop iteration having  `$value==8` and therfore `$active=''`.

Comment: "you can not use a variable in other file without passing it through any function or url or session variable" - what? http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php says otherwise: "For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well."