# Why PHP variables are persistent within loop cycles?

Tags: php, variables, scope

The following code should never execute like that in any other language that I know (C, C++, C#, etc.)

```
<?php

$do = true;

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    if($do===true) {
        $some_variable = 666;
        echo $some_variable;
        $do = false;
    }
    if(isset($some_variable)) {
        echo $some_variable;
    }
}
```

Why PHP won't unset a `$some_variable` in next loop iteration?

Comment: Loops don't have their own scope in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP variables declared inside a foreach loop destroyed and re-created at each iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626812/are-php-variables-declared-inside-a-foreach-loop-destroyed-and-re-created-at-eac)

Comment: Seems like you can echo the variable outside the for loop even if you defined it inside. I think PHP treats those variables as some kind of global for the current page. The same won't apply for functions and classes tough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP for ; foreach variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637603/php-for-foreach-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is set in the global scope. Once the first iteration sets it, the variable remains set.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Here you can move the work to a function with its own scope. After the first iteration `$do` is set to `false`, and it no longer sets the variable:

```
$do = true;

function do_thing() {
    global $do;
    if($do===true) {
        $some_variable = 666;
        echo $some_variable;
        $do = false;
    }
    if(isset($some_variable)) {
        echo $some_variable;
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    do_thing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just make sure you unset the `$some_variable` in the first iteration.

```
<?php

$do = true;

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {

    if($do===true) {
        $some_variable = 666;
        // echo $some_variable;
        $do = false;
    }
    if(isset($some_variable)) {
        echo $some_variable;
        unset($some_variable);
    }

}

?>
```

The point is that since you create the $some_variable in the first run of the loop, it will be available in all the subsequent runs of the loop, unless you specifically unset it again.