# PHP Global Comportement On Iteration

Tags: php, global

I'm currently experimenting a weird comportment, while iterating on a global var another global var take it's value

This code

```
$lang_list = array('fr_FR', 'en_US');
$GLOBALS['lang_list'] = $lang_list;
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $lang_list)){
    $GLOBALS['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}else{
    $GLOBALS['lang'] = 'en_US';
}

var_dump($GLOBALS['lang']);
foreach($GLOBALS['lang_list'] as $lang){
    var_dump($GLOBALS['lang']);
}
```

return `string(5) "en_US" string(5) "fr_FR" string(5) "en_US"`

Is it expected due to something related to globals ?

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for the explanation ! :)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I always get the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$GLOBALS['lang']` refers to the same variable as `$lang`. From the [manual page for `$GLOBALS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

So when you change `$lang` in the global scope, it also changes `$GLOBALS['lang']` (and vice versa, if you change `$GLOBALS['lang']` it also changes `$lang`). Hence in your `foreach` loop, `$GLOBALS['lang']` get assigned the values from `$GLOBALS['lang_list']` in turn.

Note that if you ran this code in a function, you would get your expected result, as `$lang` in this case would be defined in the function scope, not the global scope:

```php
function test() {
    foreach($GLOBALS['lang_list'] as $lang){
        var_dump($GLOBALS['lang']);
    }
}

test();
```

Output:

```
string(5) "en_US"
string(5) "en_US"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/b5U7j)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behavior. `$GLOBALS['lang']` refers to `$lang` variable in the global scope. And there are only two scopes in PHP: global scope and local function scope (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641487/1646322) for more details).

Since `foreach` loop doesn't create a local function scope, the `$lang` variable belongs to the global scope. Thus, `$lang` and `$GLOBALS['lang']` both refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php manual. You refer to the same value in the code above.